# tmux session not persisting after detaching from that session

Tags: terminal, tmux

I'm having an issue with getting tmux to perform as I'd expect. I only learned about it today, so it'd be really helpful to get an explanation of what is going wrong.

Overview
I go to my terminal and type `tmux new -s test_session` to create a new session with a name. Once in the tmux session, I activate a conda environment, but the next part is where my problem lies. I want to exit (or, I guess, "detach") from the session, such that the session is running even when I don't have it up in the terminal window. I try `"exit"`, but don't get a response. I try `Ctrl+B, D` (`Ctrl` and `B` together, then `D`) to "detach" as well. When I use this command, it does return to my regular terminal window, but when I type `tmux ls`, I get `no server running on /tmp/tmux-2017/default`.

To the best of my knowledge, I'm following the instructions as giving to me by a coworker and several online sources, but nothing I do prevents the session from terminating once I detach. Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

TL;DR - Can't exit tmux session without terminating it.

Answer (score 0):

Each command in tmux is preceded by the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> keystrokes, and then followed by the keystroke for the tmux command. But what written cheat sheets and tutorials seem to assume is that the reader is going to understand that the tmux commands are case-sensitive.

For example, in one source I looked at, they write the command for creating a new window as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. Everything is capitalized, so it's not clear if the <kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> should be upper-case or lower-case. The default assumption is that since the <kbd>shift</kbd> key is not explicitly invoked, then you don't need it. But that is false.

In order to properly write out the command, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> needs to be typed out without using the shift for the <kbd>b</kbd>, but in the case of the "new window command", <kbd>C</kbd> needs to be pressed while holding down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key.

I looked at 4-5 different sources on this topic and none of them made this fact explicitly clear. It took [this video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yl7NFenTgIo) to finally reveal that missing detail. (It's also a good starter tutorial, btw).